# How was Marin returned to his normal state?

Tags: fairy-tail

As we know [Marin Hollow](http://fairytail.wikia.com/wiki/Marin_Hollow) was turned into small in **chapter 456:Order** as shown in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBcqT.png) by [Brandish](http://fairytail.wikia.com/wiki/Brandish_%CE%BC). In **chapter 466:Assassins** we see him turning to his normal state as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXiM9.png). Brandish is tied with anti magic shackles, so she can't use magic. Marin's magic is **Spatial Magic** and has shown space manipulation magic at **Caracole Island**. So how did he return to his normal form? Does Spatial Magic have some other magic that helped him to return to his normal body? If it was due to Spatial Magic then why Lucy was trying to not get caught in Brandish Mass Manipulation magic?